# Moodle empty space on the front page

Tags: php, moodle, frontpage

I have got empty section on moodle front page and cannot fix it anyhow. Please help me. I am using space theme on my moodle site.[image: Screentshot of empty space]
And another small thing is that my logo is centered on the page at the top but I would like it to be completely removed.[image]
Can you help me? I have searched all the theme settings, maybe I am missing smth. Please help!
Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Moodle front page settings

Comment: Right click on the empty space and use inspect element (in Chrome) to see if there are id's, that might give you a clue